# Assistance required to split long Latex algorithm (algorithm2e) into two pages

Tags: latex

I am trying to split the algorithm into two pages but it is not working. Can any one help me with that please? I have tried to "breakablealgorithm" method described in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33866/algorithm-tag-and-page-break/33869#33869) but still it did not work. I am free to change the package but I will be needing the vlined algorithm which makes it easy to read the loops and functions.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[]
        \SetAlgoLined
        \KwResult{Automatic System Update}
        \textbf{Pseudocode:}\\~\\
        \SetKwFunction{FUpdateSYS}{UpdateSYS}
        \SetKwFunction{FBuildEnsembleClassifier}{BuildEnsembleClassifier}
        %       \textbf{Declare} temp\_results = 0;\\
        %       \textbf{Declare} YAGER\_Fusion\_Result = 0;\\~\\
        \eIf{(Highest Prediction Index DSET \textbf{Equals} Highest Prediction Index Yager) \textbf{And} (Highest Prediction Index Yager \textbf{Not Equals} Last Index)}{
            \eIf{(Highest Prediction Value DSET \textbf{Greater Than} Threshold Value) \textbf{Or} (Highest Prediction Value Yager \textbf{Greater Than} Threshold Value)}{
                \eIf{\textit{Temp\_Buffer} \textbf{Not Empty}}{                 
                    \eIf{\textit{Temp\_Buffer} \textbf{Greater Equals} \textit{Buffer\_Level}}{
                        \FUpdateSYS($sample\_data$, $master\_labels$);\\
                        \textbf{return} "\textit{Show Respective Label}";\\
                    }{
                        \textbf{return} "\textit{Show Respective Label}";\\
                    }
                }{
                    \textbf{return} "\textit{Show Respective Label}";\\
                }
            }{
                \textbf{Initiate System Warning} "Known fault detected below threshold level";\\
                \textbf{return} "\textit{Show Respective Label}";\\
            }
        }{
            Temp\_Buffer = $sample\_data$;\\
            \textbf{return} "\textit{Show Respective Label}";\\
        }~\\
        \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{:}{}
        \Fn{\FUpdateSYS{$sample\_data$, $master\_labels$}}{
            \FBuildEnsembleClassifier;\\
            \textbf{Declare} matrix = $M1 * M2$;\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix length $n$;\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{Sum} $ALL$;\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{HorizontalCells} $HOR$ \textbf{Except Last column};\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{VerticalCells} $VER$ \textbf{Except Last row};\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{DiagonalCells} $DIA$;\\
            \textbf{Get} HOR \textbf{Sum} $H$;\\
            \textbf{Get} VER \textbf{Sum} $V$;\\
            \textbf{Get} DIA \textbf{Sum} $D$;\\
            \textbf{Declare} BlankCells =  $ALL - H - V - D$;\\
            %           \textbf{Declare} K =  $1 - BlankCells$;\\
            \textbf{Declare} M1M2 = [ ];\\
            \For {i \textbf{in} \textbf{range}(\textbf{length}(HorizontalCells))}{
                M1M2 \textbf{Append} $(HOR[i] + VER[i] + DIA[i])$;\\
            }
            M1M2 \textbf{Append} $(DIA[n] + BlankCells)$;\\
            \textbf{return} $M1M2$;\\
        }
        \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{:}{}
        \Fn{\FBuildEnsembleClassifier{$sample\_data$, $master\_labels$}}{
            \textbf{Declare} matrix = $M1 * M2$;\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix length $n$;\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{Sum} $ALL$;\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{HorizontalCells} $HOR$ \textbf{Except Last column};\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{VerticalCells} $VER$ \textbf{Except Last row};\\
            \textbf{Get} matrix \textbf{DiagonalCells} $DIA$;\\
            \textbf{Get} HOR \textbf{Sum} $H$;\\
            \textbf{Get} VER \textbf{Sum} $V$;\\
            \textbf{Get} DIA \textbf{Sum} $D$;\\
            \textbf{Declare} BlankCells =  $ALL - H - V - D$;\\
            %           \textbf{Declare} K =  $1 - BlankCells$;\\
            \textbf{Declare} M1M2 = [ ];\\
            \For {i \textbf{in} \textbf{range}(\textbf{length}(HorizontalCells))}{
                M1M2 \textbf{Append} $(HOR[i] + VER[i] + DIA[i])$;\\
            }
            M1M2 \textbf{Append} $(DIA[n] + BlankCells)$;\\
            \textbf{return} $M1M2$;\\
        }
        \textbf{End Function}
        \caption{Automatic System Update}
        \label{algorithm:RBS}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can split it manually, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347920

Comment: Yes but that is using the line number. I am not showing the line numbers in the algorithm

Comment: Without line numbers that's even easier. Just don't use `\LinesNumbered
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{19}`

Comment: The manual part works... thanks but is there any way to make it automatic?

Comment: not with `algorithm2e`. In the page I linked to you'll find alternatives which are able to page break